# Reading zip file in Powershell (openread)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read zip file by openread method, but it gives error that could not find zip file.
Below is the code that I am using:

**Code:**

```
$Sourcefolder= "C:\Users\My.pc\Downloads"

$Myzipfile= gci $Sourcefolder -Filter *.zip | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

$zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($Myzipfile)
```

---

**Error:**

```
Exception calling "OpenRead" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find file 'C:\Users\My.pc\15367448612289827.zip'."
At line:4 char:1
+ $zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($Myzipfile)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException
```

---

What should I do? any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$Myzipfile` to `$Myzipfile.FullName`:

```
$zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($Myzipfile.FullName)
```